# MATMSG/Mailto QR Code • CC BCC Fields?

Tags: qr-code

With much searching online, I cannot find an answer.

I am basically wondering if it is possible to add a CC or BCC field to a QR Code.

Has anyone successfully done this? If so, what QR Encoder and Decoder are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, it is possible.  The `mailto` syntax will let you write something like

```
mailto:recipient@example.com?cc=other@example.com&subject=hello
```

Encoding that into a QR code looks like.

[image]

That said, none of the readers I tried on Android handled it correctly.  They all got the To field and the Subject field - but they wouldn't pick up on the cc or bcc fields.

I would suggest that you set up an email alias which will auto CC / BCC addresses.  So an email to test@example.com gets forwarded to alice@example.com and CC'd bob@example.com as well.

Comment: If the OP is interested in making a patch to https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/result/EmailAddressResultParser.java I can commit it. This would make CC and BCC work for Barcode Scanner and thus a lot of other readers on Android. +1

Comment: @Sean Owen - I don't have the knowledge to create a patch for that. It is a great idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, use this format:

`mailto:<email>?cc=<email>&bcc=<email>&subject=<subject>&body=<body>`

P.S. Register not important, so u can use bcc, Bcc or BCC.

Tested.